# Set product inventory per day for lessons

Tags: inventory, date

Hello I have been out of the Magento sphere for a while, hopefully someone can point me in the right direction, or tell me I can't do it. I am looking for a way to set up an inventory/limit for a product that would be based upon date, not just an arbitrary number for all.

We want to sell ski lessons online, but need to limit the number of lessons ordered per date/time per day.

**Ex.**

Some one wants to buy a lesson for 1:30pm on the 25th.

Jan 25.

- 10am - 2 available
- 11am - 2 available
- 12pm - 1 available, 1
  ordered
- 1:30pm - 2 available
- 2:30pm - 0 available 2 ordered